# UILabel autoLayout not working fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I set a `UIlabel` in `UITableViewCell` I want to make the height of `UITableViewCell` dynamically ,so I add some constraints with `UILabel` ,When enter the `UIViewController`,the label and the height of `UITableViewCell` is not correct,but if I scroll the `UITableViewCell` out of screen and  scroll it back to screen ,then it work correct,It's Strange。

This is my constraints in storyboard

[image]

UILabel in TableViewCell when enter the UIViewController

[image]

It shoule be

[image]

I have try to add the code (override UILabel)

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

and set the content hugging priority with 1000

Comment: is your target platform iOS8? or iOS7?

Comment: both in iOS7 and iOS8

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your constrains to code as IBOutlet. So just try it with a height constrain that programmatically change with UITableViewCell height.

Answer (score 0):

it happening because of your label height is larger than it's text content.if you set background color to it then you can see that.don't pin the bottom of label with bottom of the cell it will stretch the label height.

[image]

or you can try

```
[lable sizeToFit];
```

after setting the string value to the label it may fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the priority of the bottom space constraint to "Low".  Its fighting with the content hugging

Answer (score 0):

Use these constraint as per you requirements:

**title lable:**[image: image1]



**text lable:**
and `textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;`

[image: image2]

**Output**

[image]

Follow these links [Autolayout](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/) or [Autolayout programatically](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)